# How can I convert integer to binary character in Java Card?

Tags: javacard

How can I convert a byte array to binary array in Java Card to get the result as `10101010`?

```
RandomData random_data =
  RandomData.getInstance(RandomData.ALG_SECURE_RANDOM);
// the seed is supplied in the byte array seed
random_data.setSeed(sseed, seed_offset, seed_length);
// a random number is written into the byte array random_num
random_data.generateData(random_num, random_num_offset,
                         random_num_length);
```

Comment: And in JC context `num` is of type `short`?

Comment: Why do you want to want to have an array of bits? Do you want to perform specific operations on the bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A byte array is already a binary representation of a set of bits (just like a short array for that matter). The only difference with a bit array is that you will always get the bits in sets of 8, and that you cannot address each bit individually without doing some bit-wise operations.

Normally the representation of bits in a `String` (a piece of text) is not performed on card. It is performed after the bits are transmitted to the application on the terminal. You may have noticed the absence of the `String` type on Java Card classic.

---

As requested some method to convert bitjes (bits in Dutch) to characters for Java Card. Thanks for the puzzle.

```
/**
 * Converts an array of bytes, used as a container for bits, into an ASCII
 * representation of those bits.
 * 
 * @param in
 *            the input buffer
 * @param inOffset
 *            the offset of the bits in the input buffer
 * @param bitSize
 *            the number of bits in the input buffer
 * @param out
 *            the output buffer that will contain the ASCII string
 * @param outOffset
 *            the offset of the first digit in the output buffer
 * @return the offset directly after the last ASCII digit
 */
public static final short toBitjes(final byte[] in, short inOffset,
        final short bitSize, final byte[] out, short outOffset) {
    for (short i = 0; i < bitSize; i++) {
        final byte currentByte = in[inOffset + i / BYTE_SIZE];
        out[outOffset++] = (byte) (0x30 + ( (currentByte >> (7 - (i % BYTE_SIZE))) & 1 ) );
    }
    return outOffset;
}
```

Feel free to rename "bitjes" of course.

---

Usage:

```
// buffer containing 9 bits valued 10011001.1 in middle of buffer
final byte[] inBuffer = new byte[] { 0x00, (byte) 0x99, (byte) 0x80, 0x00 };
final short bitSize = 9;
// bit array starting at byte 1 
final short inOffset = 1;

// or use JCSystem#makeTransientByteArray()
final byte[] outBuffer = new byte[40];
// ASCII start at offset 2
final short outOffset = 2;

// newOffset will be 2 + 9 = 11
short newOffset = toBitjes(inBuffer, inOffset, bitSize, outBuffer, outOffset);
```

Comment: You can easily translate a byte array to an ASCII representation of bits (I'm happy to provide the code), but that's probably not what you require.

Comment: I'll let you guess the value of `BYTE_SIZE`. It should be a `short` 8OP

Comment: could you give me an example about parameter please,I mean value of in,inoffset,bitSize,out and outOffset when I aplay toBitjes.

Comment: OK, but that's the last edit if you don't mind. If you like you can vote up too.

Comment: yes of course,I will vote number that you want,you deserve.what I require exactely is to convert the byte array named random_num in the code that I montioned to ascii code,if you can tell me haw I can implemented it with example please.

Comment: this code doesn't give me binary code with lenght of 8 for example:10011001 or other.please help me,mybe I didn't well understant.

Comment: You use the generated random array as input buffer, with the `random_num_offset` as `inOffset` and `random_num_length * BYTE_SIZE` as `bitSize`, and any buffer (e.g. the APDU buffer) as output buffer.

Comment: but the code that you are give it to me give me result as 11 and me i want binary code like 10011001 lenght equal 8

Comment: What did you try Meriem? I don't see too much unclarity in the interface I specified.

Comment: the code is clear but I wonder if this code can give me the result like 10011001 rather than 11.thank you

Comment: About vote I try to vote up but it doesn't work,you can tell me haw i can vote up.thanks

Comment: he tell me the vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.

Comment: You cannot vote up twice, maybe that's what you are trying to do? Or do you want to remove your vote? I think the API works as should be expected, I've tried it out on my computer (using Java SE, but that should not matter)

Comment: yes that what I'm trying to do,I mean vote up.about your programme it work well but it dont give result that I require.My question was haw to get binary caracter that have 8 charecter lenght,like this 10011001 and you programme give me as result 2 binary character 11.do you understund what I'm talking about now?

Comment: To be honest, reading back all of the text, no, I'm was not and I am not sure.